# Vue's TransitionGroup doesn't changes text like expected

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I have an array of objects like this:

`[ { word: 'example', guessed: false }, {word: 'another', guessed: true } ]`

and this is my TransitionGroup component

```js
<TransitionGroup
    appear
    tag="div"
    class="flex gap-y-4 gap-x-6 flex-wrap relative"
    enter-from-class="-translate-y-full opacity-0"
    leave-to-class="-translate-y-full opacity-0"
    enter-active-class="duration-500"
    leave-active-class="duration-500"
>
    <p
        v-for="each in anagramsList"
        :key="each.guessed"
        class="uppercase font-medium text-xl underline underline-offset-4 tracking-wider"
        :class="{ 'text-primary-300': !each.guessed }"
        v-text="each.guessed ? each.word : each.word.replace(/./g, '-')"
    />
</TransitionGroup>
```

this code is working, it shows the words side by side, if the word wasn't guessed yet, it shows just the "----" (dashes), if it was, shows the actual word...

**Setup**

Vue 3 and Tailwindcss

**The problem**

The transition when the word changes (from the dashes to the word) works, but they don't change places like they were absolute position, the new word appear on the side before the dashed word disappear

**the dashed word disappearing and the new word appearing should happen in the same spot in the array, but they are being added and removed normally** like adding a new item to the array

**My attempts**

- I've tried adding "mode="out-in"" in the TransitionGroup tag
- I've tried adding an "key" property in each object, with a "Symbol()" from vue
- I've tried wrapping the "p" tag inside a normal "Trasition" and wrap that in a "template" tag to do the v-for